# "Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:" Web3.js[1.0.0] with Node , getting this error with sendSignedTransaction

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, ether

Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction( data ).once( 'transactionHash', (hash) => {
    console.log('hash')
  }).once('receipt', (receipt) => {
    console.log('receipt');
  }).on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => {
    console.log('confirmation');
  }).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  }).then( (receipt) => {
    console.log('finally got the receipt!');
  })
```

The error which I'm getting on execution is as given below:

```
Error: Failed to check for transaction receipt:
{}
    at Object._fireError (/..../node_modules/web3-utils/src/index.js:56:17)
    at /..../node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:260:23
    at <anonymous>
```

Any help resolving this'll be much appreciated.

Comment: Which provider are you using? There have been similar issues reported recently (https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1255 and https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1534) which seem to be tied to some previous versions of `geth`. If you're using `geth`, make sure you're on the latest version (1.8.8 as of today).

Comment: @AdamKipnis Having a similar but different problem in `geth` *1.8.13*. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410883/sendsignedtransaction-gives-error-failed-to-check-for-transaction-receipt